# Query is not a function error with firestore & firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to get docs from a collection, called "posts", in firestore. I'm using a query for this as it lets me add parameters for the doc request like the number of docs requested and their order.

I've imported query from 'firebase/firestore' and used it in my code, but the imported "query" doesn't highlight itself like it should when an import or variable is used in vs code acting as if it wasn't used. However the issue is, I get an error :

> TypeError: query is not a function.

```
import PostFeed from '../../components/PostFeed';
import UserProfile from '../../components/UserProfile';
import { getUserWithUsername } from '../../lib/firebase'; 
import { firestore } from '../../lib/firebase';
import { query, getDocs, collection, limit, where, orderBy } from 'firebase/firestore';

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const { username } = query;
  const userDoc = await getUserWithUsername(username);

  let user = null;
  let posts = null;

  if (userDoc) {
    user = userDoc.data();
    const postsQuery = query(
      collection(firestore, 'posts'),
      limit(5),
      where('published', "==", true),
      where('username', "==", username),
      orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    );

    posts = (await getDocs(postsQuery)).docs.map(postToJSON);
  }

  return {
    props: { user, posts },
  };
}

export default function UserProfilePage({ user, posts }) {
  return (
    <main>
      <UserProfile user={user} />
      <PostFeed posts={posts} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Any ideas of what I should do or what the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `query` twice in this code:

```
import { query, getDocs, collection, limit, where, orderBy } from 'firebase/firestore';
        // 

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
                                          // 
  const { username } = query;
  const userDoc = await getUserWithUsername(username);

  let user = null;
  let posts = null;

  if (userDoc) {
    user = userDoc.data();
                     // 
    const postsQuery = query(
      ...
```

The last `query` in that snippet refers to the `getServerSideProps({ query })` one, and not to the import from Firestore.

The solution is to give the parameter to your `getServerSideProps` a different name:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ qry }) {
  const { username } = qry;
  ...
```

---

From the discussion in the comments, it seems you need:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(req) {
  const username = req.query.username;
  ...
```

Comment: Hey, the changes you gave me work but now I get another error which I've looked into but I dont really get why it happens. Here is the error : "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'qry' as it is undefined."

Comment: It looks like there is no `username` property in your `qry` argument. I must admit that I'm not certain what the `{}` in this code do `function getServerSideProps({ query })`, so hopefully somebody else knows that.

Comment: I believe that in the tutorial, he does this to get whatever value is in the url. So for example with this "http://localhost:3000/jeff235", the value would be jeff235. Is that not the correct way of getting that value?

Comment: You might want to use `export async function getServerSideProps(qry)` (so without the curlies) and then see what `qry` is and whether it has either a `query` or a `username` property.

Comment: I tried to console.log qry and at the end of the statement, I found this :               
  "query: { username: 'jeff235' },
  resolvedUrl: '/jeff235',
  params: { username: 'jeff235' },
  locales: undefined,
  locale: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined"

Comment: I fixed my issues, thank you for the help! I just had to remove the squiggly parentheses when I create the username const.